# Net::IMAP fails: Connection Closed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imap

When I try to open a connection to my Office 365 service, it fails as so:

```
2.2.0 :001 >     require 'net/imap'
=> true 
2.2.0 :002 >     port = '993'
=> "993" 
2.2.0 :003 >     imap = Net::IMAP.new('outlook.office365.com', port)

Net::IMAP::Error: connection closed
  from /Users/cameronaziz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/imap.rb:1077:in `initialize'
  from (irb):3:in `new'
  from (irb):3
```

What else do I need to set?

This is the code in my controller:

```
require 'net/imap'
port = '993'
imap = Net::IMAP.new('outlook.office365.com', port)
imap.authenticate('LOGIN', '***@***.com', '***')
imap.examine('INBOX')
```

It fails on the `new` command (same as the console) before I actually set the username / password.

~~~~~~~

Setting the `:ssl => true` works. But now I still can not connect, as I get:

controller:

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new('outlook.office365.com', {:port => '993', :ssl => true } )
imap.authenticate('LOGIN', '***@***.com', '***')
```

error on view:

```
Net::IMAP::BadResponseError in EmailsController#connect
 Command Argument Error. 11
```

And the highlighted line in the view is on the `authenticate` method line now.

When I run `imap.capability`:

```
 ["IMAP4", "IMAP4REV1", "AUTH=PLAIN", "AUTH=XOAUTH2", "SASL-IR", "UIDPLUS", "ID", "UNSELECT", "CHILDREN", "IDLE", "NAMESPACE", "LITERAL+"]
```

Comment: Based on `imap.capability`, you need to authenticate with one of those methods. `LOGIN` won't suffice, as it isn't supported by your IMAP server. `Net::IMAP` does appear to support `PLAIN`, however: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/imap/rdoc/Net/IMAP/PlainAuthenticator.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Port 993 is usually the way t connect via SSL IMAP so you need to tell ruby you need to connect via SSL such as:

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new('outlook.office365.com', 993, ssl: true)
```

Then you can use login or authenticate to connect to your user's mailbox.

The [ruby doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/imap/rdoc/Net/IMAP.html#method-i-authenticate) state that if you use authenticate method, you need to make sure the imap server can support "LOGIN" or "CRAM-MD5" but in the list you provided i don't see any of those.

["IMAP4", "IMAP4REV1", "AUTH=PLAIN", "AUTH=XOAUTH2", "SASL-IR", "UIDPLUS", "ID", "UNSELECT", "CHILDREN", "IDLE", "NAMESPACE", "LITERAL+"]

So the only way to login to outlook imap is to use map.login method such as:
`imap.login(login, password`)

Comment: Indeed, you need to use login function, not authenticate function.

Answer (score 3):

IMAP is probably closing the connection because you aren't authenticating in time (or at all).

You should authenticate with either the `Net::IMAP#login` or the `Net::IMAP#authenticate` method.

From [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/net/imap/rdoc/Net/IMAP.html):

`imap.authenticate('LOGIN', 'username', password)`

This should also work:

`imap.login('username', 'password')`

Keep in mind that `LOGIN` may not be the authentication method in your case. You may want to call `imap.capability` first and determine whether to proceed with either `LOGIN` or `CRAM-MD5`.

Comment: updated the question, I don't know how I would set the user / pass when it fails on the `new` method

Comment: Looking at the docs, I don't think `Net::IMAP.new` takes its `port` argument as a plain integer - it takes it as a member of a options hash. Did you try `Net::IMAP.new('outlook.office365.com', { port: port })`?